# Alternative to width/height: 0px

Tags: jquery, html, css

I have a texbox that appends text to a label when a button is pressed. 
I want the texbox and button to dissapear when the text is appended.

The jQuery script looks as follows:

```
$('.opret').click(function () {
    $('#quiznavn').text($('.navn').val());
    $('#quiznavn').css({ "visibility": "visible" });
    $('#navngiv').css({ "visibility": "hidden", "width": "0px", "height":"0px"});
});
```

However, when i inspect the page, the button is still there, yet not visible.. This is not convenient.. how would i make it totally dissapear? Does it have to do with ajax?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use

```
"display" : "none"
```

instead of

```
"visibility": "hidden"
```

or just

```
$('#navngiv').hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `hide()` function to hide an element like this.

```
$('#navngiv').hide()
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `display: none`, as that "physically" removed the element, while `visibility: hidden` simply hides it.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to make it so the button is REALLY not there anymore (not even when you inspect the html code), you have to do something like this:

```
$('#navngiv').remove();
```

Comment: Can i still toggle it back again, if the user wants to edit the text appended?

Comment: You could, but in that case it's better to use `$('#navngiv').hide()` and `$('#navngiv').show()`. It's still possible to use `remove()` and such, but it's more complicated and less efficient.